# Текстовое поле Input

Tags: html, javascript

Что нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на текстовое поле открывалось окно, т.е. выполнялась функция javascript "mark(link);" ? Что я делаю не так? Порыскал в интернете, кое-что нашёл, но не сработало. Помогите, пожалуйста.

> `<script type="text/Javascript">
> function mark(link) {
> var src = "http://dnevnik2010.ucoz.ru/files/teacher/"+x+".html";
> var params = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
> window.open(src, "Отправление оценки", params);
> }
> function null(name) {
> document.getElementById(name).value = "&nbsp;"
> }
> </script>
> <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="#3366FF">
> <tbody>
> <tr>
> <td class="pupil">Имя</td>
> <td><input type="text" name="a" value="" size="2" onclick="mark(this.name);" onchange="submitForm(this.name);" onchange=""></td>
> <td><input type="text" name="" value="" size="2" onclick="mark(this.name);" onchange="submitForm(this.name);"></td>
> <td><input type="text" name="" value="" size="2" onclick="mark(this.name);" onchange="submitForm(this.name);"></td>
> </tr>
> </tbody>
> </table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя ставить имя функции 'null()' в Javascript. Из-за этого всё и не работало.

Answer (score 2):

1. Имя "null" для функции - очень плохая идея. JS-парсер - не приемлет такое и прекращает всякую обработку скрипта.
2. Функция mark(link) - в теле этой функции LINK нигде не используется. Зато упоминается X, которая "ReferenceError: x is not defined". Я так думаю, что вместо X должна стоять LINK.

Если вы исправите эти ошибки, то увидите, что ваш код прекрасно работает и открывает окна.

Comment: Если честно, я с этими ссылками и окнами напутал, потом исправлю, потому что в данный момент проблема не в этом. То есть получается, что JS не понимает функцию null(name)? Я попробую.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Значение null является литералом JavaScript, представляющим нулевое или «пустое» значение, то есть, когда нет никакого объектного значения. Это одно из примитивных значений JavaScript